# Can a many to many relationship be modeled as a map with keys being the values from the other entity?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a following database schema.

```
CREATE TABLE asset (
    id INT,
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE property (
    id INT,
    name NVARCHAR(128)
)

CREATE TABLE asset_property (
    assetId INT,
    propertyId INT,
    value NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

For readability I would like to have it modeled as a following entity.

```
@Entity
public class Asset implements Serializable {
    ...
    Map<String, Asset_property> properties;
    ...
}
```

As the asset_property entity would hold some additional information about the relationship I need it to be available here. The property entity is not that important. I only care about its 'name'. I would like the keys of the map to be taken from the 'name' column of the 'property' table. I've read the Oracle docs about using maps in entities, but cant seem to figure this one out.

Comment: The way the data is represented in the database and the way you want to represent it in the code don't marry up. A single `Asset` object can have multiple `AssetProperty` objects which then each link to single `Property` objects. I think you'd have it as a list/set of `AssetProperty` objects on the `Asset` object. Then if you needed a collection of the Property Names that link to that `Asset`, you could use a `Map<AssertProperty, String>` where the `String` is the `Property` name value. This map could be instantiated after querying the database, or mapped during the query.